# 95 Honda civic ex, OBD port not giving check engine light codes

Tags: honda, civic, cel, obd-i

On my 95 Honda civic ex, the check engine light has been on for a while, so I wanted to check what for. I looked up where to find the OBD port, and found it under the glovebox. It looked somewhat like this:

http://cdn.instructables.com/FSX/9QXV/F6S8S0A5/FSX9QXVF6S8S0A5.LARGE.jpg

Except they were both plugged into eachother, and plugged into another port. I tried shorting the OBD port and turned the car keys until the check engine light came on, but it didn't flash or anything like it should have. Checked fuses and everything, nothing was wrong. No clue what it could be, thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't think that is the OBD-I port, as most vehicles have them located on the driver's side or center of the car, not on the passenger side. I'd look up under the dash on the driver's side and see if you can find it.

Comment: several pre-obd2 hondas have a diagnostic connector near the passanger kick panel that looks like an unused harness connector. placing a jumper between the terminals should cause the check engine light to flash. counting the number of flashes should show which codes are stored in the module. is it an automatic or manual transmission?

Comment: When I have the chance to check I'll try looking in the center, or on the drivers side, but from most of the guides/pictures I've seen they say its by the passenger side. Maybe there may be a different connector though, and it is a manual transmission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

When the Malfunction Indicator Lamp (MIL) has been reported on, do the following:

1. Connect the SCS Service Connector to Service Check Connector as shown. (The 2P Service Check Connector is located under the dash on the passenger side of the car.) Turn the Ignition Switch on.
2. Note the Diagnostic Trouble Code (DTC): The MIL indicates a code by the length and number of blinks. The MIL can indicate multiple problems by blinking separate codes, one after another. Codes 1 through 9 are indicated by individual short blinks. Codes 10 through 43 are indicated by a series of long and short blinks. The number of long blinks equals the first digit, the number of short blinks equals the second digit. Sometimes the first blink is difficult to see; always count the blinks twice to verify the code.

Comment: The picture clears it up a lot more, I disconnected the 2 pin plug, along with the other plug, the 'data link connector' I think, they were both attached to each other. Should I plug the data link connector back in then, and try again?

Comment: its worth a shot. you won't damage anything by plugging the DLC back in and jumping the SCS terminals. you're just supplying a ground signal to the ecm. leave the key OFF until you have the jumper (i usually just use a paperclip) in place. turn the key ON to the 2nd position and watch the light...

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tips! I can't do anything with the car atm, but after easter I'll try and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video on how to get HONDA CODES:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8M5BaAa6tCM